# Manipulate MySQL DB through symfony/Doctrine CLI commands

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm abel to see the results of adding an entity (php console doctrine:generate:entity) and  updating the schema (php console doctrine:schema:update –force), the table appears in phpMyAdmin.

However after deleting the entity file and running a successful update of the schema the table remains in the db as obsereved by phpMyAdmin.

As the creation process affects the observable db is there not a corresponding set of commands that removes the table from the database?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I think it could be dangerous if the console would drop all the tables wich haven't got an entity class. Otherwise how could notice the console wich table exists because an entity previously deleted?

Comment: What do you want to do? Deleting a table? Do you need to do it from Symfony2 console? Have you tried to use [MySQL from command line](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-drop-tables.htm)?

Comment: No, I don't NEED to do it from Symfony.  I'm new to both Symfony and Doctrine and I'm very partial to symmetry. What you create in one environment you should be able to delete in the same enviroment